# Github API: get commit statistics for all branches

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to use Github's API to get [statistics](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#participation) for a branch that has multiple active branches. As far as I can tell, though, the API only gives results from the default branch. Is there a way to get those statistics from across branches?

Comment: No, currently that's not possible via the API. But you could just create local Git clones of repositories and compute the statistics yourself for all branches.

Comment: Oh, interesting. It looks like `git shortlog -sn --branches` could be a good candidate for doing it that way.